# Add caption under a figure at the upper right corner

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got a page like this and I want to create a caption under my image located somewhere around the upper right corner:
[image]

```
\chapter{Background}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
   \node[xshift=-5cm,yshift=-5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4cm]{vortex_shedding.png}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{vortex_shedding.png}{hi} 
\end{figure}
```

How should I proceed?
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please include the document class and the required packages to your code to make it compilable.

Answer (score 2):

Place the `\captionof` in the `tikzpicture`, in a `\node` where you specify `text width`. The `figure` environment is unnecessary.

Note that the first argument of `\captionof` defines the float type (`figure` in this case), not the image file name.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Background}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
   \node[xshift=-5cm,yshift=-5cm] (img) at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=4cm]{example-image}};
  \node [below,text width=7cm] at (img.south) {\captionof{figure}{This is the caption for the image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```